# Entity Framework one-to-one relationship mapping flattened in code

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have a table structure like so.

```
Address:
AddressId int not null primary key identity
...more columns

AddressContinental:
AddressId int not null primary key identity foreign key to pk of Address
County
State

AddressInternational:
AddressId int not null primary key identity foreign key to pk of Address
ProvinceRegion
```

I don't have control over schema, this is just the way it is.

Now, what I want to do is have a single Address object.

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public County County { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set }
    public ProvinceRegion { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have EF pull it out of the database as a single entity. When saving, I want to save the single entity and have EF know to split it into the three tables.

How would I map this in EF 4.1 Code First?

I've been searching around and haven't found anything that meets my case yet.

**UPDATE**

An address record will have a record in `Address` and one in either `AddressContinental` or `AddressInternational`, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An address record will have a record
>   in Address and one in either
>   AddressContinental or
>   AddressInternational, but not both.

This requirement makes your first requirement impossible to achieve. @OpticalDelusion shown you the way how to map entity splitting but it only works if all parts are required. EF is not able to do this conditionally. Moreover if you try to save a new splitted entity it will always create a new record in all 3 tables.

What you need is not flattened object but TPT (table-per-type) inheritance where you will have:

```
public abstract class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class AddressContinental : Address
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class AddressInternational : Address
{
    public string ProvinceRegion { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AddressContinental>().ToTable("AddressContinental");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AddressInternational>().ToTable("AddressInternational");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Fluent API I would use.

```
mb.Entity<Address>()
  .Map(m =>
  {
    m.Properties(p => new
    {
      p.AddressId
    });
    m.ToTable("Address");
  });

mb.Entity<Address>()
  .Map(m =>
  {
    m.Properties(p => new
    {
      p.AddressId,
      p.County,
      p.State
    });
    m.ToTable("AddressContinental");
  });

mb.Entity<Address>()
  .Map(m =>
  {
     m.Properties(p => new
     {
       p.AddressId,
       p.ProvinceRegion
     });
     m.ToTable("AddressInternational");
  });
```

Comment: This seems to only work (when retrieving) if there is both a record in the continental AND international. There will be one record in Address and one record in either Continental or International, but not both. I didn't mention that. I'll update the question.

Comment: I up-voted your answer too. Thanks for solving the originally stated issue.